# How i can turn off autocompletion in Extjs combobox?

Tags: extjs, autocomplete, combobox

When I selected some item in combobox and then I'm trying to select another item in same combobox, I can see only one item - those which is selected right now. I believe that happens because of autocompletion. Does anybody know how I can disable it or something. I need to see all values on each click, regardless if something was selected already or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `triggerAction:'all'` to your config.

Answer (score 1):

better add `disableKeyFilter:'true'` to your combo box